# UN evento sucede a determinada hora del dia SQL server 2008 R2

Tags: sql-server

A las 1 PM en un Juego X muere un monstruo pero este se programa para que dentro de  tres Horas aproximadas Reviva, Osea este sale a las 3 PM. por decir ejemplo pero la hora de revivir es Variable NO TIENE HORA FIJA entonces

consegui que:

```
DECLARE @horarevive int 
    SET @horarevive = 3

SELECT DATEADD(HOUR, @horarevive, GETDATE()) AS revirira
```

necesito hacer un select que detecte la hora "revivira" si llego la hora o pasa de la hora ejemplo de ello, pero en dias si este fuera cada 3 dias.

```
SELECT revirira FROM Table WHERE >= GETDATE ()-3 --esta sentencia debe detectar si murio hace mas de 3 dias o Mas 4,5,6,7,8 Infinito---> pero en Horas
```

**necesito hacer el select pero en horas** como seria? para detectar si ya revivio por que son las 3PM o un poquito mas para que yo pueda hacer algo como esto:

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT Hora FROM Table WHERE Hora >= `aqui Desconozco que colocar de select tiempo de Hora`)
BEGIN
Print 'Update Revivir consulta'
END
```

la hora es variable, osea que el tiempo de reaparición es diferente en cada mounstruo. Tengo una tabla donde se informa la hora en la que debe revivir el monstruo.

Ejemplo: el monstruo muere el dia 04/10/2018 a las 13 horas y revive 10 Horas depues osea  a las 23 Horas del dia 04/10/2018 y luego a las 23 horas con 15 vuelve a morir para revivir a las 9:15 del dia 05/10/2018 esta Info de muerte esta en una Tabla que sale la muerte del Monstruo. en otra esta la hora en la que revive. la pregunta es **¿como hago el select de la coluna de hora revivio?** is el formato de la columna es: **2018-10-04 13:00:00.767**
osea si hago esto puedo hacerlo pero el resultado seria Dias y no las horas.

`SELECT revivido FROM TABLE WHERE Columna <=GETDATE()-10`

sale en 10 dias y lo necesito es en Horas.

Comment: ¿Y si haces un `job` que ejecute ese evento?

Comment: no se que es un Job

Comment: Lectura recomendada https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/ssms/agent/create-a-job?view=sql-server-2017

Comment: gracias bro pero no me sirve primero la hora no es FIJA segundo es trabajo por triggers y si se ejecuta las condiciones y tres aun que fuera por AgentSQLmanager no tengo la opcion asi que debo buscar el select solicitado. por que los Jugadores hacen el Jefe de Monstruos en diferentes Horas segun es el Player vs player

Comment: Dices que la hora es variable, osea que el tiempo de reaparición es diferente en cada mounstruo? A eso te refieres? Tienes una tabla donde persiste esa información? Lo tuve que leer varias veces para entenderlo un poco. Luego si tienes registrada la fecha hora en la que murió deberias usar datedif para saber si ya ha pasado el tiempo para q vuelva al juego. Hubiese sido mas facil con una mejor explicación o algo mas de tus tablas.
Ojalá te sirva, si me das mas info podria ser mas específico

Comment: Daniel exactamente como dices, si si tengo una tabla que dice en cada hora que murio el Monstruo lo que use la consulta para definir la hora en la que revive, pero no logo ver o mejor dicho saber como hacer select si esa hora paso asi como dices tu exactamente. perfecto lo explicastes mejor que yo